# JSOUP scraping a data

Tags: java, jsoup

Hi i need to scrape a web site using JSOUP and i needed to get output in key- value pairs can anyone suggest me.
The url which i need to scrape is https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls?field_rc_date_value%5Bmin%5D&field_rc_date_value%5Bmax%5D&field_rc_heading_value=&field_rc_hazard_description_value=&field_rc_manufactured_in_value=&field_rc_manufacturers_value=&field_rc_number_value=

The code which i written is:

```
package com.jaysons;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;  
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;  

public class ScrapeBody {  
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException{  
String url = "https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls?field_rc_date_value%5Bmin%5D&field_rc_date_value%5Bmax%5D&field_rc_heading_value=&field_rc_hazard_description_value=&field_rc_manufactured_in_value=&field_rc_manufacturers_value=&field_rc_number_value=";  
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();  
    
Elements content = doc.select("div.views-field views-field-php");      
doc = Jsoup.parse( content.html().replaceAll("</div>", "</div><span>")
.replaceAll("<div", "</span><div") );  
Elements labels = doc.select("div.remedy");  
for (Element label : labels) {  
System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", label.text().trim(),                                                                                    
label.nextElementSibling().text()));
}  
}        
}
```

i need output in key value pairs like
Date:OCTOBER 20, 2017
remedy:
units:
website:http://www.bosch-home.com/us
phone:(888) 965-5813

kindly let me know where did i do mistake

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? And what is your question? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. If you're wondering where to start, you could check out the project documentation, for example the [cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/).

Comment: i had tried so many versions but nothing seems working,so i was aking for some help  -  ventiseis

Comment: Please show what you have tried then.

Comment: check my code which i edited in my post  @sina

Comment: Why are you undoing the edits to improve the formatting of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres no need to reassign and re-parse the value of the `content` variable.

```
Elements content = doc.select("div.views-field >span");
for (Element viewField : content) {
    /*
        each viewField corresponds to one
        <div class="views-field views-field-php"> 
          <span class="field-content">
            <a href="/Recalls/2018/BSH-Home-Appliances-amplía-retiro-del-mercado-de-lavavajillas">
            <div class="date">
              October 20, 2017
            </div>
            ...
          </span>
        </div>
    */
    Elements divs = viewField.getElementsByTag("div");
    for (Element div : divs) {
      String className = div.className();
      if (className.equals("date")) {
        // store and extract date
      } else if (className.equals("...")) {
        // do something else
      } // else...
    }
}
```

Not only you can select subelements by tag, but also by name, by some attributes etc. Check the official documentation for more info: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

Disclaimer: I could not test the code right now.

Comment: this code was not running fine moreover i need to get output in key value pairs but here it was not working

Comment: You can make the key value pairs inside the second (inner) loop. If the `className` equals `date`, you create a key-value-pair for the date, if it equals `remedy`, you extract the remedy information and create a key-value-pair for that data etc. This code is not a complete solution for your problem, but should be enough to lead you in the right direction.

Comment: yupppp thank you for your help,i got that and it was working fine @sina

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer then :)